# Java Apache FTPClient API: Why isn't logout() in finally clause?

Tags: java, ftp, logout, ftp-client

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

I noticed the example disconnects() in the finally clause, but doesn't do the same for logout()

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
config.setXXX(YYY); // change required options
ftp.configure(config );
boolean error = false;
try {
  int reply;
  ftp.connect("ftp.foobar.com");
  System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");
  System.out.print(ftp.getReplyString());

  // After connection attempt, you should check the reply code to verify
  // success.
  reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

  if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftp.disconnect();
    System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  ... // transfer files
  ftp.logout();
} catch(IOException e) {
  error = true;
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if(ftp.isConnected()) {
    try {
      ftp.disconnect();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
      // do nothing
    }
  }
  System.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Anyone know why we don't need to logout() when we catch an exception?

Comment: Because it is preferable. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone know why we don't need to logout() when we catch an exception?

The inside code of [`ftp.logout()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java#FTPClient.logout%28%29) function is as follows:

```
public boolean  logout() throws IOException
{
         return FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(quit());
}
```

The `quit()` function send a command using `sendCommand(FTPCommand.QUIT)` to the `FTP Server`. If  a connection exception happens, we are likely not being able to connect with `FTP Server`. calling `logout()` will try to write to FTP server again and create resources with additional throwing exception. In addition, although `disconnect()` function will also throw an exception, it closes the `input, output, socket` and releases resources which `logout()` function doesn't: as it is evident from the following source code of [`disconnect()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/2.0/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.java#FTP.disconnect%28%29) function:

```
 public void disconnect() throws IOException
 {
      if (_socket_ != null) _socket_.close();
      if (_input_ != null) _input_.close();
      if (_output_ != null) _output_.close();
      if (_socket_ != null) _socket_ = null;
      _input_ = null;
      _output_ = null;
       _controlInput_ = null;
       _controlOutput_ = null;
       _newReplyString = false;
       _replyString = null;
 }
```

Comment: Is there actually any reason to call `logout` if you're about to call `disconnect` anyway? Or is `logout` only useful in the (very rare) situation where you want to log straight back in as a different user?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about the FTPClient library but I believe it's safe to assume disconnecting from the server implies logging out as part of the process if applicable, considering the explanations given in the docs:

disconnect() : Closes the connection to the FTP server and restores connection parameters to the default values.

logout() : Logout of the FTP server by sending the QUIT command.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html